# Covering map implies biholomorphism?

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

Suppose $f: X \to X'$ is a (holomorphic) covering map between hyperbolic surfaces (that is, their universal covering is the unit disk $\mathbb{D}$). Letting $p: \mathbb{D} \to X$ and $p': \mathbb{D} \to X'$ be the universal coverings, one can obtain a lifting $\tilde{f}: \mathbb{D} \to \mathbb{D}$ after choosing some points. Then apparently this lifting is biholomorphic. I see why $\tilde{f}$ is a holomorphic map, since it is locally a composition of holomorphic maps, but I don't quite see why it must be a bijection. So my question is exactly that, is $\tilde{f}$ a bijection?

**Edit:** I added the section in which this problem appears, as mentioned in the comments.
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, you can only conclude that $\tilde{f}: \mathbb{D} \to \mathbb{D}$ is a covering map (and therefore a Blaschke product?).

Comment: I came across this when reading Milnor's Dynamics in One Complex Variable where he proves Pick's Theorem. He left this part as an exercise however, so I would hazard to guess that it is true. I can't see why this holds though.

Comment: I have downloaded the lecture notes from https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9201272. Can you tell which part you are referring to?

Comment: It appears that he has proved Pick's Theorem in a different way in his lecture notes compared to his textbook. He does mention something along the lines of this problem in page 2-2 in Lemma 2.2.

Comment: I added the section in which this problem appears, with the cited exercise, if the textbook is inaccessible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your map $\tilde{f}$ is the unique basepoint-preserving map such that $p'\tilde{f}=fp$, using the lifting property of the covering map $p'$.  However, $fp:\mathbb{D}\to X'$ is also a covering map (since it is a composition of covering maps of locally simply connected spaces). So we could also lift $p'$ along $fp$, and get a basepoint-preserving map $\tilde{p}':\mathbb{D}\to\mathbb{D}$ such that $fp\tilde{p}'=p'$.

I now claim that $\tilde{f}$ and $\tilde{p}'$ are inverses, and so in particular $\tilde{f}$ is a biholomorphism since they are both holomorphic.  To prove this, note that $p'\tilde{f}\tilde{p}'=fp\tilde{p}'=p'$.  So, $\tilde{f}\tilde{p}'$ is a basepoint-preserving lift of $p'$ along itself.  But another such lift is just $1_\mathbb{D}$, so by the uniqueness of lifts along covering maps, this means $\tilde{f}\tilde{p}'=1_\mathbb{D}$.  Similarly, $\tilde{p}'\tilde{f}=1_\mathbb{D}$ since they are both lifts of $fp$ along itself.